# How to iterate and find from map<pair<string, int>, pair<string, Array>>?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, stdmap

This is my map:

```
map<pair<string, int>, pair<string, Array> > matchMap;
```

This is the function:

```
void Schedule::studentSchedule() 
{
    string s, c;
    cout << "Enter the student and course name to create schedule" << endl;
    cin >> s >> c;

    list<string>::iterator studentLoc;
    map<pair<string, int>, pair<string, Array> >::iterator courseL;

    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(), getStudentList().end(), s);
    courseL = find(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), c);

    if (studentLoc != getStudentList().end() && courseL != getMatchMap().end())
    {}
}
```

I can not find the string here because I am getting an error:

```
courseL = find(getMatchMap().begin(),getMatchMap().end(),c);
```

How can I find the element which I want ? This is the error:

```
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/algorithm:61,
                 from C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\SchoolProject1\Schedule.cpp:4:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Value = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:104:42:   required from '_InputIterator std::__find_if(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate, std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:3905:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > > >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\SchoolProject1\Schedule.cpp:24:63:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > >' and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/algorithm:61,
                 from C:\Users\Fatih\Desktop\clion\SchoolProject1\Schedule.cpp:4:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_iterator.h:860:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)'
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)?

```
courseL = matchMap.find(pair<string, int>{c, 1});
```

The key to your map is of type `pair<string, int>`, so to use find you need to provide a valid key.

Comment: I tried like this but i get an error again. No matching member function for find error

Comment: `void Course::addCourse()
{
    string a;
    int b;
    int total;
    int courseAdd;
    cout<<"How many course you want to add?"<<endl;
    cin>>courseAdd;
    cout<<"Enter the name of course and number of hours.\nWARNING:For now just enter max 6 course hours"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<courseAdd;++i)
    {
        setCourseName(a);
        setHours(b);
        getCourseList().insert({a, b});
        total += getHours();
        shuffleVector();
        getMatchMap().insert({make_pair(a,b),make_pair(getDay1()[i],dayHours)});
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Out of all, see this error,

```
no match for 'operator=='
(operand types are 'std::pair<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, 
std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::array<int, 6> > >'
and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
```

The key of your map (i.e. `getMatchMap()`) is `std::pair<std::string, int>`, not just `std::string`, and you are passing only the `std::string`.

You need

```
std::find(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), std::make_pair(s, /*some integer*/));
//                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or more appropriate would be using the [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) member function.

```
const auto iter = getMatchMap().find(std::make_pair(s, /*some integer*/));
```

Comment: But i just have to find the course name in the map. Not the int.

Comment: As I undertand the error causing from the getMatchMap function. I changed teh code with Dror Moyal's answer and it seems work.

Comment: When I do this solution, i cant find these pairs on the map when i run the code. The integer int the map is users defined integer and we dont actually know what is in there. Is there a way to find the course name without sending an integer?

Comment: courseL = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(),getMatchMap().end(),(courseL->first).first == c );  I changed the code like this but im getting errors again.

Comment: error: expression cannot be used as a function
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I am trying to find the getMatchMap's element not the studentList's.

Comment: I wrote a predicate func for it : bool Schedule::predicateFunc(map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator &it,string &c)
{
    if((it->first).first == c)
        return true;
}

Comment: find_if(getStudentList().begin(), getStudentList().end(), predicateFunc(courseL,c));

Comment: However i dont know how to use this in if statement

Comment: bool Schedule::predicateFunc(map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator &it,string &a)
{
    return ((it->first).first == a);
}

Comment: @sonelektrikci Sorry I was out from the place. I was wrong about the iterator, in the previous comment. BTW, your predicate concept is wrong. The unary predicate will only take one argument. In your case, the entire key-value pair. If you use [tag:C++14] you could write a **[generic lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)**. See here for a complete minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/HsNRsT. Since this is another problem, **I would suggest opening another question.**